# C implementation of a linked list remove element function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, linked-list

I was reading a textbook and came across the following function to remove an element from a linked list.  The `CELL` type is defined as follows;

```
typedef struct CELL CELL;
struct CELL {
    int element;
    CELL* next;
};

void delete(int x, CELL** pL) {
    if ((*pL) != NULL) {
        if (x == (*pL)->element)
            (*pL) = (*pL)->next;
        else
            delete(x, &((*pL)->next));
    }
}
```

Now suppose I have a linked list with the following elements starting at 5;

`5->10->3->21->15->7`

Now suppose I delete element 10.  My question is what happens to the `CELL` containing 10 when the `delete` function returns now that this `CELL` is unreferenced?  Isn't it still taking up space in memory?

Comment: Get a debugger step through the code, and examine the variables.

Comment: Unrelated, that function is exemplary of the principle : "just because you can doesn't mean you should." That algorithm *easily* ports to an iterative solution. Likely used as part of a recursive solutions for data-structures course/lesson, it may serve its purpose there, but avoid it in-practice.

Comment: Yes, it is still taking up space, although it is not clear how the element was allocated. It may be better to keep the `delete` function agnostic about memory management and return a pointer to the `CELL` that was deleted (or `NULL` if no cell was deleted) and let the caller free it. You could have a wrapper function that also frees the element. The other odd thing about this function is the use of tail recursion instead of iteration. If the compiler does not optimize that, you could get a stack overflow if the list is long.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not freeing any memory in your code, it should still be there somewhere. You just unlink that element from the linked list.

Depending on how you manage the memory for these elements this might or might not be a problem (memory leak). For example, if each element is allocated using `malloc` and the linked list has the only pointer to that element then you most likely have a memory leak (and using `free` is required). But if the nodes are allocated on the stack (e.g. using `alloca`) or in some memory pool which is freed later, then there might not be a leak. So it really comes down to how you handle the memory and when do you deallocate it.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm so used to the variables of user-defined types being heap dynamic from Java that I forgot that they could also be stack dynamic in C.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> what happens to the `CELL` containing 10 when the delete function returns now that this `CELL` is unreferenced? Isn't it still taking up space in memory?

Absolutely! Once the function returns, the `CELL` containing 10 becomes a memory leak, unless there is another pointer referencing it, or the `CELL` is *not* allocated dynamically.

If other functions for manipulating the list (creating, inserting, etc.) are implemented in such a way that they assume list's ownership of its cells, add a call to `free` in the branch that re-points `*pl` to `(*pL)->next`. Make a temporary variable, store the address of `*pl` in it, do the re-pointing, and call `free` on the temporary.

Comment: Thank you.  Before you posted I thought about deleting the statement in between the inner `if` and `else` and adding the following three statements in order;  `int* temp = (*pL)->next;`, `free(*pL);`, and `*pL = temp;`  Now I'm wondering, would this accomplish the same, or would it be better to do it the way you stated?

Comment: @BlaqICE Yes, it would accomplish the same thing: it does not matter if you use `temp` for the node that you wish to delete, or for the node that you wish to keep, so both approaches would produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

For starters some remarks about the function itself. It would be better to declare the function the following way

```
int delete( CELL **pL, int x );
```

In fact the function does two things. It searches a node with the value equal to x. And it unlinks a node if such is found.

So it is desirable that the function would report whether such a node is found.

Another way to declare the function in case when the function does not free the removed node pointed to by **@IanAbbott** in a comment is

```
CELL * delete( CELL **pL, int x );
```

That is the function returns pointer to the removed node or NULL if such a node with the value equal to x is not found.

Secondly it is better to declare the first parameter as a reference to node and the second parameter as searched value. That is at first what you are dealing with and then how you are dealing with the list.

As for your question then the function as I already said unlinks a node. The node itself is not removed from memory and is not changed. If it was allocated dynamically then you have to keep a copy of the pointer pointing to the node. Otherwise there will be a  memory leak because you will be unable to free it without having a pointer to the node.

Comment: You could return a pointer to the deleted node instead of an `int`. Return `NULL` if not found. Then the caller can do whatever it needs to do to free the node.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes it is an alternative approach.